# Why does the button open the video file but not download it?

Tags: html

When I click the button, this opens up the video. I want to make it such the it would download the media file rather than playing it. What is wrong in my code?

```
<p id="btnDownload">Download <a href="video/bg-space.mp4" download="bg-space">here</a></p>
```

Comment: I think that might be your browser setting, you can always right click and save target as

Comment: That´s true, thanks

Comment: Like Huangism said, it may be your browser config. This could help you if you still want to download it with a click: [Force download with JavaScript](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-download)

Comment: Thanks, Im gonna try